# In MS Project :the resource calendar did not show up in the gantt chart but it shows at the resource usage sheet

Tags: ms-project

the resource calendar did not show up in the gantt chart but it shows at the resource usage sheet:
i mean that, i assigned the Friday and Saturday as days off in some resources (i am using the resource calendar ) but at the gantt chart it shows that this days are a working days and calculated the total duration according to that.  [image]

[image]

Comment: Just a suspicion: Are you using more than 1 calendar?

Answer (score 0):

> the resource calendar did not show up in the gantt chart but it shows
>   at the resource usage sheet

The green shading on the Gantt chart is based only on the Project Calendar* and is for display only. However, Microsoft Project does take into account the Resources' base calendars and Task calendars (if used) when scheduling tasks (e.g. determining the start and finish dates).

See [Work with calendars in Project](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/work-with-calendars-in-project-323ff403-a676-428c-be11-6942bfb7210c) and [Understanding the Power of Calendars in Microsoft Project](https://www.senseiprojectsolutions.com/2017/06/16/understanding-the-power-of-calendars-in-microsoft-project/) for more information.

Note: the Gantt Chart Nonworking time can be formatted to show shading for a different calendar; the default is to shade based on the Project Calendar.